# Prepending Text to Variable Value in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an off-boarding script I wrote to cycle users out of the company. Part of that process is I append TERM_ to the email address in the AD user object properties then rename the user object to prepend TERM_ then I modify the object and prepend TERM_ to the Full Name and Last Name. At that point I run my script and paste in the TERM_user@mycompany.com and the script does the rest. That part is handled with like this:

```
 $newupn = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter NEW UPN" #Will be TERM_jdoe@mycompany.com
 $oldupn = $newupn -replace ".*_"
 $samacct = $newupn -replace "@.*"
```

What I would like to do is cut out those first renaming steps and simply enter the samaccount name or the DisplayName as my input and have the script prepend TERM_ where needed.

The issue I am having is when I try to get the displayname or fullname to a variable the result is including the command in the written output or includes the quotes.

Comment: can you share the code that is assigning the variable?

Comment: I don't see how  your code prepends anything to the `$newupn` string..

Comment: For the display name I am trying the code is:       Set-ADUser -Identity $samacct -DisplayName "$($term)($_.DisplayName)"    The resulting change to the user object is  TERM_(.DisplayName)  and I want to see TERM_User, Test                  For renaming the ad object itself I am trying to use                               Get-AdUser $user | Rename-ADObject -NewName { "$term" + $_.Name }   and the result is the object is renamed to                  "$term" + $_.Name

Comment: Does anyone have any insight?